# how to test django registration app process while in development server (no mail)

Tags: django, email, registration

I am developing a django application on my MAC.  The development server that comes with django is great.  However, I installed the django-authopenid (combines django-registration app with openID) which follows the 3 step process:  user signs up, app sends a confirmation email with link, and user clicks on link to confirm sign-up.

Since the django development server does not have a mail server, how do I test this confirmation email portion of the process?  I followed an idea to print out the contents of the email to the terminal, but I can't follow the link. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

Python has a debugging mail server available for this purpose.

Just execute this command and you'll have a mailserver running at port 1025

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

After that you'll need to change your `MAIL_HOST` setting in Django and you can test your emails locally :)

Comment: ok, so I am running this, but I the link from the email throws an error.  The link is: <a href=3D"http://openid-example.e-engura.org/account/activate/e29864d921cd=
1455e63a150e6ea122adbbe4a158/">/account/activate/e29864d921cd1455e63a150e6e=
a122adbbe4a158/</a>.

Comment: Do I need to change this somewhere.  Thanks.

Comment: That link is generated with the sites framework. In the Django admin you can change the site url to something that will work (like `localhost:8000`)

Comment: I changed it in the 'activation_email.txt' file that is used to generate the email.  Thanks again!

Comment: The changes to settings.py (or settings_local.py if you have that configured) are: 
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

Answer (score 9):

If you have a Gmail account, you can use it to send your dev mail. Put the following in your settings.py file:

```
# django-registration
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'YourEmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'YourGmailPassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'DevBox <YourEmail@gmail.com>'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Answer (score 5):

The following additions to `settings.py` will make it so all emails sent by your django apps are written to `<PROJECT_ROOT>/dev/email/` (or choose another directory):

```
# I put this at the top of all my settings.py files
import os
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Somewhere later
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = path(ROOT, "dev", "email")
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally love django-extensions (https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

It adds a manage.py command called 'mail_debug' that does what WoLpH recommended automatically.

It also comes with a ton of other great debugging and dev tools like runserver_plus, show_template, show_urls, etc...  (I really wish django-extensions would get rolled into Django already!)